# jQuery on change triggering before value is changed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using jquery to change the value on input fields when an option is selected from a dropdown list. The fields are initially populated with values via php

```
<label><?php echo $size->size ?></label><input type="number" name="<?php echo $lineno ?>-<?php echo $size->id ?>" id="<?php echo $lineno ?>-size<?php echo $sizeblock; ?>" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $size->qty ?>" title="">
```

These values seem to be overwritten by the jquery as soon as the page loads. How do I keep these values in the input fields until the dropdown list value actually changes? My js below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$("[id^=packs]").on('change', function() {              
var packname = this.value;
console.log("packname:"+packname);
var lineno = this.getAttribute('data-lineno');
console.log("lineno: "+lineno);
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>products/pack",
    cache: false,
   // ContentType : 'application/json',               
    data: {name: packname},
    success: function(json){                        
    try{        
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
        console.log(obj);
        console.log("size1: "+obj.packdetail[0].size1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code works as expected. When the values of the form where saved, I did not change the ids to correspond with the database update. Therefore the actual database fields had 0 as values and it was not a PHP problem.